# How to simulate string?

Tags: physics

I want to make a group of party balloons. The strings on the balloons should have slack or be tight based on the length of the string and the location of the balloon. I thought the best way to start this would be to take a long thin cylinder and place it at the base of the balloon. How can I use physics to simulate this long thin cylinder as string?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Based upon [this balloon tutorial](http://matica.com/tutorials/blender/blender-simulating-a-balloon-tutorial):

- Create a string
- Create a bone as the "handle" (which you can then move around as you please)
- Use the cloth simulator to simulate the string and use weight painting to select the part of the string you want to use.