# Animation attaching a string to a balloon

Tags: animation, physics, cloth-simulation

[image]So I have two objects... a UV sphere and a rope that I modeled. All I want to do is have two different cloth physics (one for sphere, one for rope) and basically attach the sphere to the rope. The whole idea is to have the sphere raising up and dragging the rope with it.
Could someone kindly explain how I attach two objects with two different cloth physics please? I'm struggling a bit.
Thank you!

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/629/how-to-simulate-string

Comment: I did follow the balloon simulation link above using the copy location constraint.. but objects just  seperate.

Comment: @MattB If you followed the instruction in the attached Balloon sim answer and it was still separating then most likely one of your vertex groups or the soft body goal vertex group is wrong or the constraint not correctly configured.  Go through the process again or download the sample blend file and compare that with your setup. Failing all that, post images of your constraints, soft body settings, vertex groups, etc. and if possible an animated gif of your results.